# How to generate Request Body like this [{"key":"available","value":"1"}] in Retrofit?

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, retrofit2

My server is accepting request body like this:

```
[
 {
  "key":"available",
  "value":"1"
 }
]
```

I have a interface like this:

```
@POST("lm/leave")
suspend fun requestLeave(
    @Body body: RequestBody
): Response<LeaveResponse>
```

What I have tried:

```
val lReq: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    lReq.put("available", "1")
```

How and what should I use to generate a request like above ? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) and [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) to create the request you need:

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject()
jsonObj.put("available", "1")

val jsonArray = JSONArray()
jsonArray.put(jsonObj)

val requestBody = RequestBody.create(null, jsonArray.toString())
requestLeave(requestBody)
```

`JSONObject` is responsible for the creating of object data representation in a json format:

```
 {
  "key":"available",
  "value":"1"
 }
```

`JSONArray` wraps the object into an array representation:

```
[
    {
     "key":"available",
     "value":"1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks but is this the right way for a request body ?

Comment: If server accepts it and doesn't return an error, then it is ok.